# "in the last 12 months hotel revenue is up by 6% over any previous year" over ANY previous year?

Tags: any

I found this sentence in a news site, but I don't understand the meaning of the last part.

Since 2019, Clarksville-Montgomery County has added over 6,000 new jobs and, even with the decline in travel from the pandemic, in the last 12 months hotel revenue is up by 6% over any previous year.

Is it possible to paraphrase this sentence with "...in the last 12 months hotel revenue is up by 6%, and this rate is better than any year in the past" or "this rate is the highest rate ever"?

Or does this sentence have any other meaning?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The revenue in the past 12 months is 6% higher than the revenue in the previous highest year (whichever that was). It is, therefore, the highest revenue for any year. The sentence does not say that the revenue is up by 6% in the last 12 months. Personally I would avoid 'rate', which has main meaning of 'the speed at which something happens or changes, or the amount or number of times it happens or changes in a particular period'

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Michael. Do you mean that 6% is not compared to the previous year? Hmmm... But why do you use "any" here, if you mean "6% higher than the previous highest year"?

Comment: It's a valid word choice. 'Any previous year' means 'any single previous year out of all the previous years that the hotel has been in business'. 'Any' can mean 'one of or each of a particular type of person or thing when it is not important which'.

Comment: Yes, but in this case, it is important which year you are referring to, because you are comparing the last decade and THE highest revenue year in the past.  That's why ANY sounds weird to me.  Thank you.

Comment: @Taro - the text you quoted compared the last 12 months (not the last decade) with _any previous year_.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You are right. But my question remains. Why do you use "any" for the single highest revenue year?

Comment: 'Of any previous year' means 'of every single one of the previous years'. I am taller than any of my friends' means 'I am taller than every single one of my friends'

Comment: Yes, but you can't be 6% taller than any of your friends.

Comment: @Kosuke - yes you can. "FiveThirtyEight [a supercomputer] predicts Manchester United have the best chance of clinching the Europa League trophy in May. The supercomputer gives Ole Gunnar Solskjaer's side an 11 per cent chance of winning the competition - a whole **three per cent more than any of the 31 other teams** in contention. (UK Daily Mirror 16 February 2021). "The city [Saskatoon, Canada] collects 22 per cent of its operating budget through utilities, **three per cent more than any of the other cities**.  (Global News, Canada).

Comment: @Kosuke - if my little son is 106 cm tall and his friends are 100, 92, 95, and 98 cm tall, then my son is 6% taller than any of his friends.

Comment: Thank you for all the examples from news. I really appreciate it. They are all so interesting to me.

Comment: Now I think I understand this usage of comparison and any.  Thank you.